# How to sort a dictionary based on the order in the dictionary?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list. In the list, I want to show the key in the list, but I want them to be sorted the way how they are in the dictionary. I tried a method, but I think that they are ordered alphabetically or something like that. I will paste what I've tried so far below.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
            let privacyDictionary = [strings.personalProfile: strings.settingsOn,
                                     strings.personalOffers: strings.settingsOf,
                                     strings.generalOffers: strings.settingsOn,
                                     strings.contactChannels: nil
            ]
            let sortedPrivacyItems = privacyDictionary.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
            ForEach(sortedPrivacyItems, id: \.key) { key, value in
                ListItem(title: [key], statusText: value, icon: .listitem_chevron_right, type: .clickable)
            }
        }
```

The desired list: personalProfile, personalOffers, generalOffers, contactChannels.

Thank you !

Comment: Dictionary aren't ordered. If you need a specific order, you might have an array of "ordering". And with `sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })`, you're ordering by alpha on the `key`.

Comment: Is the dictionary dynamic, or will it always have these four keys? If so, get rid of the `ForEach` and write out the 4 `ListItem`s. If not, don't use a dictionary in the first place and use an array of pairs instead. Also consider an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md).

Comment: @Sweeper Is not dynamic, it will always be the same keys. The values instead, it will be modified later with a value from the backend, this is only a placeholder for now

Comment: Well then as I said, write 4 `ListItem`s. "Unroll" the `ForEach`.

Comment: Also avoid defining variables (like `privacyDictionary`) inside the view element definition. Instead, make it a property of the View (as @State). Otherwise it will be reinitialized every time the view is redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

I try this but I'm not sure is the solution.

```
import SwiftUI

struct IndexedKey: Hashable {
    let key: String
    let index: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            let privacyDictionary =
            [IndexedKey(key: "x", index: 0): "av",
             IndexedKey(key: "a", index: 1): "bv",
             IndexedKey(key: "b", index: 2): "cv"
            ]
            ForEach(privacyDictionary.sorted(by: { elm1, elm2 in
                elm1.key.index < elm2.key.index
            }), id: \.key.index) { elm in
                Text("\(elm.key.key), \(elm.value)")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```